# Representation of linear functional on $c$

Tags: operator-theory

On the space of convergent sequences $c$ let $x=(x_i)_{i\in \Bbb N}\in c$ and $\lim_{i \to \infty}x_i=x_0$ then a bounded linear functional on $c$ has a representation $$x^\ast(x)=y'x_0+\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_iy_i$$ where $y=(y_i)_{i\in \Bbb N}\in l_1$ and $y'$ is a constant.
Show also that $||x^\ast||=|y'|+||y||_l$

I hope I've been clear enough, Thanks.

Comment: What does $\lim_{x\to 0}$ mean here..?

Comment: I fixed it sorry :)